# PHP function strtotime giving wrong value when using 'First Saturday'

Tags: php, strtotime

In the UK, the day is currently 27th January 2015.

I want to find the 1st Saturday in this month and use the following code, but instead of giving me the expected 3rd January 2015, it shows 31th January 2015? What have I done wrong or is there a bug in `strtotime`? My PHP Version is `5.4.16`

```
$time = strtotime('First Saturday');
$month1 = date("Y-m-d", $time);
echo $month1;
```

The above outputs 2015-01-31 and not the expected 2015-01-03

Comment: That is because IT IS the 31 on saturday?

Comment: Errr... it depends where you start counting from. I guess PHP starts counting from now, since you didn't provide it any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to pass month and year(or any date) also for expected

```
$time = strtotime('January 2015 First Saturday');
$month1 = date("Y-m-d", $time);
echo $month1; //2015-01-03
```

cause "first saturday" is calculate from the date given. If given date already is a saturday, the next one is calculated. so you don't given any date then it's calculating from now next saturday, so try pass a date

Comment: Doh, you are quite right. "First Saturday" means the 1st Saturday after a given date. I took it to mean the 1st Saturday in the month. Many thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

```
$time = strtotime('First Saturday of this month');
$month1 = date("Y-m-d", $time);
echo $month1; //2015-01-03
```

Comment: With no extra explanation this makes for a bad answer.